# .NET CosmosDB NoSQL query to match object model

Tags: .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am new to noSQL and struggling to understand what data is actually passed to the constructor of T when calling

```
GetItemQueryIterator<T>(query).
```

Most of the examples I find are using "SELECT * FROM mytable" and the object model used in queries is the full representation of the myTable data scheme, like including all fields.

But what if I just want to select a few field from a large table in a particulat query ? Do I need to have as many data model types as many different queries ?

To be more precise, let's assume I have documents in a container similar to below. I am only interested in the Body nested JSON data, all the rest is actually pushed there by Azure IoTHub when feeding data to CosmosDB:

```
    {
    "id": "fa14e6f9-b340-4b86-b7b2-46c58318bce5",
    "partitionKey": "VK_THC_Outside",
    "Properties": {},
    "SystemProperties": {
        "iothub-connection-device-id": "VK_THC_Outside",
        "iothub-connection-auth-method": "{\"scope\":\"device\",\"type\":\"sas\",\"issuer\":\"iothub\",\"acceptingIpFilterRule\":null}",
        "iothub-connection-auth-generation-id": "638151591628992733",
        "iothub-content-type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        "iothub-enqueuedtime": "2023-04-08T19:10:50.932Z",
        "iothub-message-source": "Telemetry"
    },
    "iothub-name": "lackoiothub",
    "Body": {
        "Temp": "3.30",
        "Hum": "91.30",
        "SBattery": "3532.00",
        "GBattery": "4466",
        "RSSI": "-48",
        "Version": "4",
        "TimeStamp": "2023-04-08T19:10:37Z"
    }
},
```

Now I don't want to model or query the whole document, only part of it using a query like this :

```
   var query = new QueryDefinition(
  "SELECT i.Body.Temp, i.Body.Hum, i.Body.SBattery, i.Body.GBattery, i.Body.TimeStamp " +
  "FROM iothub i " +
  "WHERE i.partitionKey = \"VK_THC_Outside\" and i.Body.TimeStamp >= @minDate " +
  "ORDER BY i.Body.TimeStamp desc"
  ).WithParameter("@minDate", DateTime.Today);
```

I assume I will have the fields retruned as Temp, Hum, SBattery, GBattery and TimeStamp thus I created a model object :

```
public class SensorData
{
public string temp { get; set; } = "0";
public string hum { get; set; } = "0";
public string sbatt { get; set; } = "0";
public string gbatt { get; set; } = "0";
public DateTime time { get; set; }

public SensorData(string temp, string hum, string sbatt, string gbatt, string time)
{
  Debug.WriteLine($"Sensordata.ctor() : temp: {temp} hum: {hum} sbatt: {sbatt} gbatt: {gbatt} time: {time}");
  try
  {
    this.temp = temp;
    this.hum = hum;
    this.sbatt = sbatt;
    this.gbatt = gbatt;
    this.time = DateTime.Parse(time);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Debug.WriteLine($"Sensordata.ctor() : Exception : {ex.GetType().Name} {ex.Message}");
    this.time = DateTime.Now;
  }
}
}
```

Putting this all together, I have below code:

```
      var query = new QueryDefinition(
  "SELECT i.Body.Temp, i.Body.Hum, i.Body.SBattery, i.Body.GBattery, i.Body.TimeStamp " +
  "FROM iothub i " +
  "WHERE i.partitionKey = \"VK_THC_Outside\" and i.Body.TimeStamp >= @minDate " +
  "ORDER BY i.Body.TimeStamp desc"
  ).WithParameter("@minDate", DateTime.Today);


  using FeedIterator<SensorData> feed = container.GetItemQueryIterator<SensorData>(query);

  while (feed.HasMoreResults)
  {
    var sData = await feed.ReadNextAsync();
    sData.ForEach(d => _sensorsData.Add(d));
  }
```

Turns out this does not work and I am getting no or weird data passed to SensorData constructor. Thanks to the debug messages I can see that data is not passed as expected. No data is passed for the constructor of SensorData for parameters sbatt, gbatt and time either:

```
Sensordata.ctor() : Exception : ArgumentNullException Value cannot be null. (Parameter 's')
Sensordata.ctor() : temp: 3.50 hum: 91.30 sbatt:  gbatt:  time: 
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Sensordata.ctor() : Exception : ArgumentNullException Value cannot be null. (Parameter 's')
Sensordata.ctor() : temp: 3.50 hum: 91.20 sbatt:  gbatt:  time: 
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Sensordata.ctor() : Exception : ArgumentNullException Value cannot be null. (Parameter 's')
Sensordata.ctor() : temp: 3.60 hum: 91.20 sbatt:  gbatt:  time: 
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Sensordata.ctor() : Exception : ArgumentNullException Value cannot be null. (Parameter 's')
Sensordata.ctor() : temp: 3.60 hum: 91.10 sbatt:  gbatt:  time: 
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Sensordata.ctor() : Exception : ArgumentNullException Value cannot be null. (Parameter 's')
```

So I found another way to avoid deserialization in the first place and to check what data is actually being returned by the query.
For this purpose I replaced the generic GetItemQueryIterator with GetItemQueryStreamIterator, and with the same query I use the code below :

```
using FeedIterator feed = container.GetItemQueryStreamIterator(query);

  while (feed.HasMoreResults)
  {
    var response = await feed.ReadNextAsync();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.Content))
    using (JsonTextReader jtr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
    {
      JObject result = JObject.Load(jtr);
    }
```

Checking the value of variable "result" in the loop above, I now can see that actually the query result is as expected:

[image]

So can someone please point me to the right direction why

```
container.GetItemQueryIterator<SensorData>(query)
```

is not working as expected ?

Comment: Check your casing and abbreviations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to honor the capitalization of the properties or use decorators to assign which Json property matches with what class property.

The first one is the easiest one:

```
public class SensorData
{
public string Temp { get; set; } = "0";
public string Hum { get; set; } = "0";
public string SBattery { get; set; } = "0";
public string GBattery { get; set; } = "0";
public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

You could also use `JObject`:

```
container.GetItemQueryIterator<JObject>(query)
```

And use the `JObject` accessors, like `item["Hum"]` to get the `Hum` property value.

Comment: Thanks you for pointing out, I overlooked the importance of matching property names.